# Global context in node-red to store http req and res objects

Tags: node.js, global-variables, node-red

We are exploring node-red as an option for rapidly creating small utilities needed within our team.

Typical pattern we have is :
1) Get search criteria from HTTP query parameters
2) Lookup records matching those in our couchdb
3) Call one of two APIs for each result in the array
4) Combine all results into one array and return response to original request

At the step 3 , there can be several msg payloads and the flow is somehow loosing original Http req and res objects. For the final step , we are storing them in global context and using again when all results are combined.

In case of multiple requests , is there a chance of the gloabal context being overwritten ? Is that shared across multiple requests ? Or it is safe in the above scenario ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, storing `msg.req/res` into context is an anti-pattern that should be avoided. As soon as you have to handle two requests in parallel, the second one will overwrite the first.

I would start by tracking down where exactly those properties are going missing in your flow. Nodes are meant to pass on all message properties. There are some edge cases where its acceptable not to, but they are very specific.

If you find a node dropping message properties it is likely a bug with that node that needs to be fixed.

Comment: When requests split into several asynchronous API calls , what may be the recommended way to check if all records have been processed and where to store individual results in the interim ? It would be great to have a node that abstracts all this processing.

Comment: The use the join node to recombine them

Comment: Yes , using split and join nodes was the best approach here. It worked fine.

Comment: For example like someone's mongoDB node which doesn't forward a http in request ;) I could workaround with the help of a queue-gate. Once my mongoDB node outputs a result set I save it in some context, then send msg.payload = "flush" and topic = "control" to the q-gate so that the queued http request object is flushed and sent to a http response node.